# Prove that the alternating series converges.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

> Given that
>   $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}n\left(\frac{b_n}{b_{n+1}}-1\right)=\lambda>0$,
>   show that
>   $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\left(-1\right)^{n}b_{n}}\left(b_{n}>0\right) $
>   converges.

Using the definition of limit of sequence, I can prove that $\left\{b_n\right\}$ is monotonically decreasing when $n$ is large enough. But how to prove $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}b_n=0$?

Comment: The sequence is bounded below and decreasing. Now assume it didn't converge to $0$. What can you say then about $\lim_{n\to\infty}n\left(\frac{b_n}{b_{n+1}}-1\right)$?

Comment: @martin.koeberl Then it has a nonzero and positive limit (which is impossible?). But I don't know how to prove it by absurd.

Comment: I don't think it is trivial.  If $b_n$ converges to a limit greater than zero, $\frac {b_n}{b_{n+1}}-1$ converges to zero.  Certainly without the factor $n$ you couldn't claim that $b_n \to 0$

Comment: Now, you have to use the definition of convergence in various ways. The keypoints being that above limit stays above $\lambda-\frac{\epsilon}2$ for any $\epsilon$ you choose (from some point), and that you can write $\frac{b_n}{b_{n+1}}-1=\frac{b_n-b_{n+1}}{b_{n+1}}$. For the numerator, use the definition of convergence, for the denominator, use that the limit is assumed to be strictly bigger than $0$.

Comment: @martin.koeberl Why is it above $\lambda-\frac{\epsilon}{2}$?

Comment: Sorry, there was an error in my idea. I was just about to post something similar to RRL.

Comment: This proposition is stated and proved in the  classic old text Infinite Sequences And Series by Bromwich.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given $0 < r < \lambda$, there exists $N$ such that if $n \geqslant N$ we have

$$n \left(\frac{b_n}{b_{n+1}}-1  \right)> r \\ \implies \frac{b_n}{b_{n+1}} > 1 + \frac{r}{n}.$$

Hence for all $m > N$ it follows that

$$\frac{b_N}{b_m} > \prod_{k=N}^{m-1}\left(1 + \frac{r}{k} \right).$$

The infinite product on the RHS diverges to $+ \infty$ as $ m \to \infty$ since $\sum 1/k $ diverges. Therefore,  $b_m$ converges to $0$.

Answer (score 0):

If
$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}n\left(\frac{b_n}{b_{n+1}}-1\right)
=c>0
$,
then,
arguing loosely,
$\frac{b_n}{b_{n+1}}-1
\approx c$
so
$\frac{b_n}{b_{n+1}}
\approx 1+c$.

Therefore,
for any $0 < d < c$,
for all large enough $n$,
$\frac{b_n}{b_{n+1}}
\ge 1+d$.

By induction,
$\frac{b_n}{b_{n+k}}
\ge (1+d)^k$
or
$b_{n+k}
\le \frac{b_n}{(1+d)^k}
\to 0$
as $k \to \infty$.

Therefore
$\lim_{n \to \infty} b_n = 0$.

Since
$\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}
\le \frac1{1+d}$
for all large enough $n$,
$b_n$ is a decreasing sequence
for large enough $n$.

By the alternating series theorem
(alternating sign,
limit zero, decreasing),
the sum converges.